# Recursive bug in homework assignment. Looking for advice

Tags: python, recursion

I'm taking an intro comp sci course and the current project is recursive. The program reads a text file that has n number of rows and n number of columns of `-` and `I`. The program creates a 2D list
which is the grid used for the program. The user is then prompted for a point on the grid (row, col) and if the user's point is a `-` the point is changed to a `@` and then I have to recursively fill in the first available space with a `@` by checking the space above, left, right, below and filling the first space available. My recursive function is:

```
def fillWithAt(grid, the_row, the_col):

    if grid[the_row][the_col] == '-':
        grid[the_row][the_col] = '@'
        printFile(grid)

        if the_row != 0:
            if grid[the_row - 1][the_col] == '-':
                fillWithAt(grid, the_row - 1, the_col)

        if the_col != 0:
            if grid[the_row][the_col - 1] == '-':
                fillWithAt(grid, the_row, the_col - 1)

        if the_col != (len(grid[the_row]) - 1):
            if grid[the_row][the_col + 1] == '-':
                fillWithAt(grid, the_row, the_col + 1)

        if the_row != (len(grid) - 1):
            if grid[the_row + 1][the_col] == '-':
                fillWithAt(grid, the_row + 1, the_col)

    else:
        printFile(grid)
```

`grid` is the 2D list, `the_row` is the user's row, and `the_col` is the user's column.
The program works almost perfectly, but it breaks down when it gets to the last two columns.
I can't figure out how to copy the output into this because every time I try it is stripped of whitespace and means nothing, so I'll try to explain.

The program works fine until I hit the last two rows. The program finds an empty space to the right and for some reason occupies the next two spaces to the right instead of just one space. After that the program reads the spaces around the current point incorrectly. At the end of the day the program still completes the task, but I'm curious as to why the bug occurs.

I'm not looking for any answers, but advice. If anyone can see any reason as to why this might happen, I'd appreciate any info. I also love feedback/constructive criticism.

EDIT: Here are a few steps into the recursive process. The current space first checks it's above neighbor for a '-'. If a dash is found then that spaces is occupied, if not the left neighbor is checked, and then the right, and finally below.

```
- - - - - I I - - - - - - - -
- - - - I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ - - - - I I - - - - - - - -
- - - - I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ @ - - - I I - - - - - - - -
- - - - I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ @ @ - - I I - - - - - - - -
- - - - I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ @ @ @ - I I - - - - - - - -
- - - - I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ @ @ @ @ I I - - - - - - - -
- - - - I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ @ @ @ @ I I - - - - - - - -
- - - @ I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ @ @ @ @ I I - - - - - - - -
- - @ @ I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ @ @ @ @ I I - - - - - - - -
- @ @ @ I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ @ @ @ @ I I - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ I - - I I - - - - - -
- - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@ @ @ @ @ I I - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ I - - I I - - - - - -
@ - - - I - - - - I I I I - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - I - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - I - - - - - - - - I I I
- - - I - - I I I - - - I - -
- - - I - - I - - I - I - - -
- - - I I I I - - - I - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

The program works as expected until this point:

```
@ @ @ @ @ I I - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ I - - I I - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ I - - - - I I I I - -
@ @ @ I - - - - - - - - I I I
@ @ I - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ I - - - - - - - - I I I
@ @ @ I - - I I I - - - I - -
@ @ @ I - - I @ @ I - I @ - -
@ @ @ I I I I @ @ @ I @ @ - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - -

@ @ @ @ @ I I - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ I - - I I - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ I - - - - I I I I - -
@ @ @ I - - - - - - - - I I I
@ @ I - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ I - - - - - - - - I I I
@ @ @ I - - I I I - - - I - -
@ @ @ I - - I @ @ I - I @ @ @
@ @ @ I I I I @ @ @ I @ @ - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - -

@ @ @ @ @ I I - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ I - - I I - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ I - - - - I I I I - -
@ @ @ I - - - - - - - - I I I
@ @ I - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ I - - - - - - - - I I I
@ @ @ I - - I I I - - - I @ @
@ @ @ I - - I @ @ I - I @ @ @
@ @ @ I I I I @ @ @ I @ @ - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - -
```

For some reason it occupies two spaces to the right instead of one, and then on the next move it occupies both spaces above the two previously occupied spaces.

My code to generate the grid is:

```
def get2DList(fo):
    full_list = []

    for line in fo:
        full_list.append(list(line.strip()))

    fo.close()
    return full_list
```

fo is a file

EDIT: I have solved my issue thanks to @Blckknght giving me the idea that my printFile() function was the cause. It's working perfectly now. Thank you to everyone that helped!

Comment: Can you post a screencap of your output?  Seeing it would make it a lot more clear

Comment: Should you *only* fill the first of the 4 spaces that is available?

Comment: Just indent pasted text four spaces to get it to show up properly. This is fully explained in the prominent sidebar.

Comment: All your `if ... == '-'` are redundant, since `fillWithAt` makes the same check.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by filling the first space available? Do you mean replacing only `-` with `@` in the neighboring cells? Or replacing all neighboring cells? Or spiraling out and replacing cells starting from that user's position?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Maybe it is the way the grid is built? Like referencing twice the same list for the last two rows.

Comment: I am stumped too. I ran your code with your data - works as expected. Can you attach the data file _as is_?

Comment: I think @GuillaumeLemaître is on to something. Notice that the example's last column and next-to-last column are identical. Possibly the last column and next-to-last column are both references to the same data. Check that `id(grid[-1])!=id(grid[-2])` and `id(grid[0][-1])!=id(grid[0][-2])`.

Comment: @MarkRansom So I ran the id check on the points and it turns out that id(grid[0][-1]) == id(grid[0][-2]). I don't understand why it would be doing that though. Do you have any idea as to how I could troubleshoot that?

Comment: @MarkRansom Actually I ran the id check on some other points and it's always the same for spaces with '-' so I don't think that's what I'm looking for is it?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, of course there's a good chance `id` will return the same value for the same string. I'm still trying to figure out a way that the two values would point to the same object in lockstep but I can't come up with anything.

Comment: Not that it will help you with your particular problem but you could use `with open("...", 'r') as fo:` so you don't need to explicitly `close()` it. It's called a [context manager](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/) and it's super helpful.

Comment: Anyway, maybe you could throw in a [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) `set_trace()` call for when you get to that end stage, and perhaps you'll be able to see what's going on. Something like `if the_col >=7: pdb.set_trace()`?

Comment: Can you show the `printFile` function? I'm wondering if there's an output bug, rather than an issue with your recursive flood-fill.

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you for this comment, it was a bug in my printFile function and I fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a careless mistake when first coming up with the functions. My printFile() was thus

```
def printFile(current_list):
    for i in current_list:
        for j in i[:-1]:
            print(j, end = ' ')
        print(j)
    print()
```

My reasoning for this was when I first tried I used only `for j in i: print(j, end = ' ')` The problem with that was it would print an unwanted space in front of every new line, and this was the first thing that came to mind.

I now see that printing `j` outside of the for loop for the last column was a mistake because `j` was still equal to the previous iteration of the for loop, causing the last 2 columns to act the same(I'm a newbie so please don't laugh at me). My new function is this:

```
def printFile(current_list):
    for i in current_list:
        print(' '.join(i))
    print()
```

All works as expected now. Again, thank you to everyone that helped.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to figure out the problem and I re-wrote your program.  Then I noticed that you solved your problem, but it wasn't obvious because you don't have an accepted answer.  I suggest that @Blckknght should post his comment "I'm wondering if there's an output bug" as an answer and you should accept it.  Then people will know for sure that this problem is solved.

You might as well look over my version and see what you think of it.

It's possible that I used some stuff in Python that you haven't learned yet.  If so, just ignore it for now I guess.

Changes:

- I added a string to init a grid, and a function that makes a grid from the string
- I changed `the_row` to just `row` and likewise for `the_col`.  The prefix `the_` adds nothing but visual noise.
- I made an outer function that, one time, does sanity checks on the input grid, and then an inner function that just does the recursive flood fill.
- I just re-wrote `print_grid()` to use a `for` loop that loops over the grid directly, rather than using `range()`.  That's cleaner code and runs a little bit faster.
- I printed out the grid using `''.join(row)` which doesn't separate the grid characters with spaces.  This is different from what you did.  To get the spaces, simply do this: `' '.join(row)`  In other words, join the row using spaces rather than an empty string.
- I wrote this to run unchnaged on either Python 2.x or Python 3.x.  The only tricky thing is that I had to call `'print('')` instead of just `print()`, because in Python 2.x `print()` will actually print `()` rather than nothing.  (This is because in Python 2.x, `print` is a statement rather than a function, and it evaluates the `()` as an empty tuple, and prints the empty tuple as `()`!)
- I changed all names to match PEP8 standard.  (But if you are taking a class, and the teacher wants you to use camelCase names, do what the teacher says.)

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

```
# grid flood fill program
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

s_grid = """\
-----II--------
----I--II------
----I----IIII--
---I--------III
--I------------
---I--------III
---I--III---I--
---I--I--I-I---
---IIII---I----
---------------
"""

def grid_from_str(s):
    s = s.strip()
    rows = s.split('\n')
    return [list(row) for row in rows]

def print_grid(grid):
    for row in grid:
        print(''.join(row))
    print('')


def flood_fill(grid, row, col, blank='-', fill='@'):
    row_max = len(grid)
    col_max = len(grid[row])

    if grid[row][col] != blank:
        print("skipping: row {}, col {}".format(row, col))
        return

    grid[row][col] = fill
    print_grid(grid)

    if row > 0:
        if grid[row - 1][col] == blank:
            flood_fill(grid, row - 1, col)

    if col > 0:
        if grid[row][col - 1] == blank:
            flood_fill(grid, row, col - 1)

    if col < (len(grid[row]) - 1):
        if grid[row][col + 1] == blank:
            flood_fill(grid, row, col + 1)

    if row < (len(grid) - 1):
        if grid[row + 1][col] == blank:
            flood_fill(grid, row + 1, col)


def fill_grid_with_at(grid, row, col):
    row_max = len(grid)
    col_max = len(grid[0])

    assert row_max > 0 and col_max > 0

    # make sure grid is regular
    assert all(col_max == len(row) for row in grid)

    # make sure grid only contains legal stuff
    assert all(ch in ('-', 'I', '@') for row in grid for ch in row)

    flood_fill(grid, row, col)


grid = grid_from_str(s_grid)
fill_grid_with_at(grid, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into helping me. I can't believe how awesome the community is on this site. I apologize for not posting an answer(this is my first post). I really like your solution, but there are a few things I've never seen before. I'm going to read up on those in the documentation.

Comment: You're welcome!  And welcome to StackOverflow.  :-)  If you have any questions about why I made any of those changes, you can ask here.  You can also try searching StackOverflow because maybe someone already asked a similar question!  :-)  Good luck and have fun.